# HTML5 canvas with spring

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, canvas

I want to create a web application that presents some data graphically. The HTML5 canvas seems perfect for that. But I want to use Spring MVC, and thus JSP. Would that work? Can you put an HTML5 canvas in a JSP page? Does anyone have any experience of this: what are the gotchas?

---

**Edit:**
In particular, I have in mind that HTML5 is not XHTML, yet [JSP seems to require XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966399/does-using-jsp-document-jsp-in-xml-notation-imply-outputting-xhtml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clearly stated in [an answer by BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2968641/545127) to a different question, your JSP must produce well-formed XML, so you must use the "empty element syntax" for elements without content. And you should include the HTML5 `DOCTYPE` to prevent triggering of "[quirks mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695787/what-is-quirks-mode)".

Comment: To be sure, you aren't confusing "JSP" with "JSP Document" (which has `.jspx` extension)? You have nowhere explicitly stated "JSP Document" in your question. With regular/oldschool JSP it's of course perfectly possible to use non-well-formed HTML.

Comment: @BalusC well, I'm a newcomer to JSP and Spring, so I *am* confusing them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5-canvas within jsp. As long as you include the html5 syntax () in jsp and the usage of canvas. It  will work. 
Canvas works only with these browser versions. 
http://caniuse.com/canvas
For the browsers which don't support canvas either you can use pollyfills or else the functionality wont be available.
One more point - Spring MVC or anyother backend technology doesn't matter as long as you use jsp or another view which renders html to the browser.
 Thanks

Comment: "or another view which renders html to the browser": but there is no such thing as plain "HTML". HTML has multiple versions, including XHTML. All the JSP I've seen uses XHTML, which would not allow use of the `canvas` element. Are you saying you can use JSP for other than XHTML?